# How to display all attributes of model subclass on first initialization?

Tags: backbone.js

**Problem**

When a child model is initialized for the **first time**, only defaults of the child are set as attributes.

When a second(and all subsequent) child is being initialized, the attributes of child display defaults of child and it's parent.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/HMLcj/)

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "john",
        lname: "smith",
        age: 30,
        language: "english",
        location: "belgium"
    }
});

var Child = Parent.extend({
    defaults: {
        hobby: "doing nothing",
            age: 24,
        occupation: "student"
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        _.defaults(this.defaults, this.constructor.__super__.defaults);
        console.log(this.attributes);            
    }
});
```

attributes of child initialized for the first time :

```
 var child1 = new Child();
```

child1.attributes :

```
 hobby: "doing nothing"
 age: 24
 occupation: "student"
```

attributes of same Child class, initialized for the second time:

```
var child2 = new Child();
```

child2 attributes:

```
age: 24
hobby: "doing nothing"
language: "english"
lname: "smith"
location: "belgium"
name: "john"
occupation: "student"
```

**Question**

Why are not *all* defaults(child's and parent's) are being set as attributes when a child model is initialized for the first time ?

Because i've to display a `Backbone.Collection` inside a `<ul>` and every model's attributes are configurable through a html form inside each `<li>`. But because of this problem, i can't get to all attributes of the first model in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the Child class's `defaults` object when the first object is instantiated, during its `initialize` method. At that point, the Backbone.Model constructor has already used `defaults` to fill in the attributes for that object, so it will only affect subsequent instantiations.

Take a look at Backbone.Model:

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var defaults;
    var attrs = attributes || {};
    options || (options = {});
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.attributes = {};
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, modelOptions));
    if (options.parse) attrs = this.parse(attrs, options) || {};
    if (defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults')) {
      attrs = _.defaults({}, attrs, defaults);
    }
    this.set(attrs, options);
    this.changed = {};
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

`initialize` is the very last step, after the defaults have been set, so modifying `defaults` at that point won't do anything for the current object.

To get it to work how you want, modify `defaults` after you declare the class, rather than during `initialize`:

```
Child.prototype.defaults = _.defaults(Child.prototype.defaults, Parent.prototype.defaults);
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HMLcj/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot :), i missed that part, just assumed that initialize is called before all the rest. Spend hours going through all the code. You saved me many more !!!